# How can I make the sub-select menu consider changes in the main-select menu in Angular 6+?

Tags: angular

Objective: Whenever I change the option in the main select-menu I wish the sub-menu to change accordingly and show the "children"-entries from the datasource that is defined as parents in app.component.ts. How can I achieve this?

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6cskq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[ngValue]` on your main selects option tag.
Like this:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="currentParent">
   <option [ngValue]="parent" *ngFor="let parent of parents">{{ parent.title }}</option>
</select>
```